# Infinidb on Ubuntu 14.04: ERROR: Failed trying to update InfiniDB System Configuration file

Tags: ubuntu, infinidb

just started a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 LTS image, and installed the .debs for 4.6.0.1. After that, I ran the following  .... which immediately fails:

```
root@infinidb1:~# /usr/local/Calpont/bin/postConfigure

===== Setup System Server Type Configuration =====

There are 2 options when configuring the System Server Type: single and multi

  'single'  - Single-Server install is used when there will only be 1 server configured
              on the system. It's a shorter install procedure used for POC testing, as an example.
              It can also be used for production systems, if the plan is to stay single-server.

  'multi'   - Multi-Server install is used when you want to configure multiple servers now or
              in the future. With Multi-Server install, you can still configure just 1 server
              now and add on addition servers/modules in the future. This is used more for
              production installs.

Select the type of System Server install [1=single, 2=multi] (2) > 2
ERROR: Failed trying to update InfiniDB System Configuration file
```

I didn't get any further debug info nor was there any information in the syslog and /tmp/ logfiles.

I tried a 12.04.4 Ubuntu image as well, same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by setting the correct locale info in /etc/environment:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Logout, login.
After that `sudo apt-get install build-essential libxml-parser-perl expect`
 and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Then reinstall infinidb.